# Who are these teams?

Tags: riddle

Denny owns a demolition company and has successfully managed a strong, sharp team of more than 30 specialists for over 20 years. His team works well together and has decades of experience, having completed well over 12,000 demolitions and making a name for themselves. They are definitely on the cutting edge of the demolition field.

Now it's time for Denny's son to start learning to manage his own 
smaller team of 20.

---

**Denny gives his son some general rules to start him off:**

> 1. Listen to the feedback of your team members and provide them with top medical attention and care when needed.
> 2. Always clean up the workplace as soon as possible after each demolition.
> 3. Be sensitive to problems within the team- If something has come between 2 members of your team, take immediate action to find the problem and deal with it before the bonds that bind the team have a chance to deteriorate.
> 4. Work smart by allowing each worker to use his specialty. In other words, let the 8 on the Plan Team organize and begin each demolition, the 4 on the Dog Team rip through the outer walls and tear apart the infrastructure, and the 8 on the Mole Team smash what remains so that it can be carried away easily.
> 5. Lastly, allow your team to work only in private, in the dark, since most people prefer not to see or hear our work.

---

**Who are these specialized teams?**

Comment: Great riddle! The 4th point makes it possibly too easy, but without that it might be arguably too broad.

Comment: Or you could use names more interesting than Teams A, B, C. I like the idea of "the dog team" for team B and maybe "the mole team" for team C!

Comment: Nice, I like it! Of course it's already been solved, but no harm in improving it now :-)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The specialized teams are

> teeth

Denny owns a demolition company and has successfully managed a strong, sharp team of more than 30 specialists for over 20 years.

> Most adults have 32 teeth.  You could say that teeth demolish food.

His team works well together and has decades of experience, having completed well over 12,000 demolitions and making a name for themselves. They are definitely on the cutting edge of the demolition field.

> Over the course of an adult's life, he will have eaten well over 12,000 meals.  The teeth sure are on the cutting edge, cutting into food with each meal.

Now it's time for Denny's son to start learning to manage his own smaller team of 20.

> Children have 20 baby teeth.

Listen to the feedback of your team members and provide them with top medical attention and care when needed.

> If your teeth hurt, go to the dentist.

Always clean up the workplace as soon as possible after each demolition.

> It's best to brush your teeth after each meal.

Be sensitive to problems within the team- If something has come between 2 members of your team, take immediate action to find the problem and deal with it before the bonds that bind the team have a chance to deteriorate.

> If you get food stuck in your teeth, use floss to get it out.  If the food remains stuck there, it could result in pain and/or cavities.

Work smart by allowing each worker to use his specialty. In other words, let the 8 Initiators plan and begin each demolition,

> A child has 8 incisors at the front.

the 4 Shredders rip through the outer walls and tear apart the infrastructure,

> A child has 4 canine teeth, which tear apart food.

and the 8 Pulverizers grind and crush what remains so that it can be carried away easily.

> A child has 8 molar teeth, which grind food.

Lastly, allow your team to work only in private, in the dark, since most people prefer not to see or hear our work.

> It is polite to eat with your mouth closed.  People don't want to see you eat with your mouth open.

Answer (score 18):

They are

> teeth

1. > Take good care of your teeth. If your teeth hurt, go to the dentist.
2. > Brush your teeth after you eat.
3. > If there is food between your teeth, floss to prevent your teeth from rotting.
4. > Initiators are the incisors, shredders are canines, and pulverizers are molars. Total twenty teeth in children.
5. > Don't let other people see you chewing. It is disgusting!